# Bootstrap responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

How do I make a carousel, like with multiple images for system view and only one image show in mobile view..one by one image slider in a mobile.

[image: grid layout]

Answer (score 1):

In this type of scenario I always use two different codes

1.The code which will be available for desktop users and hidden for mobile users

2.The code which will be available for mobile users and hidden for desktop users

I don't know this is the proper solution or not but I use this logic and it works everytime